# Warum heißt es Bauchnabel? Gibt es ein anderes Wort mit Nabel?

Tags: noun

Warum sagt man nicht einfach nur Nabel anstatt Bauchnabel?

Comment: Ich habe drei Fundstücke gefunden.
Eine Pflanzengattung [Wassernabel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassernabel_(Gattung)) und den[Pflanzennabel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilum).
Das [Trommelfell](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trommelfell) hat auch einen Nabel den Trommelfellnabel.

Comment: Tut man doch. Mindestens eben so oft.

Comment: @Kilian Foth: Ich meinte: Warum gibt es überhaupt das zusammengesetzte Wort Bauchnabel wenn Nabel völlig ausreichen würde?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[see answer in english language below]

Deine Frage hat verschiedene Aspekte und beruht auf verschiedenen impliziten Prämissen. Ich versuche, diese Prämissen herauszurarbeiten, um eine zufriedenstellende Antwort zu geben. Ich beginne mit den allgemeinen Punkten und arbeite mich zu den spezifischeren Aspekten deiner Frage vor:

### Redundanz

Du scheinst anzunehmen, dass natürliche Sprache Redundanz vermeidet: Im Wort "Bauchnabel" ist der Zusatz "Bauch" überflüssig, wenn es keinen anderen Nabel gibt. Von einem rein **logischen** Standpunkt ist die Antwort auf deine Frage daher: Sprachen sind redundant. Siehe [en:wikipedia: Redundancy (linguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(linguistics)) für ein paar Beispiele und Erklärungsansätze, warum das ganz allgemein so ist.

Es ist nicht ganz klar, ob diese rein logische Betrachtung das ist, worauf du mit deiner Frage abzielst, aber es ist eine mögliche Interpretation deiner Frage. Natürlich lässt diese Antwort noch Fragen offen. Selbst wenn wir akzeptieren, dass Sprachen grunsätzlich redundant sind, ist es doch erklärungsbedürftig, warum gerade "Bauchnabel" diese Redundanz aufweist, aber Wörter wie *"Handfinger" oder *"Kopfauge" nicht existieren. Was unterscheidet das Wort "Bauchnabel" (das existiert) von, sagen wir, dem möglichen Wort *"Handfinger" (welches nicht existiert)?

Der Kommentar von Knut und die Antwort von Pollitzer zeigen, dass es in der Tat andere Zusammensetzungen mit "Nabel" gibt. Ich glaube aber, dass das sehr seltene Worte sind, die an Spezialkontexte gebunden sind. Ich würde schätzen, dass diese Spezialausdrücke - "Pflanzennabel", "Trommelfellnabel" und "Wassernabel" - einerseits jünger sind als "Bauchnabel" und andererseits einer großen Mehrheit kompetenter Deutsch-Sprecher*innen gar nicht bekannt sind; damit können sie auch keine logische Erklärung dafür liefern, warum das überspezifizierte "Bauchnabel" existiert und verwendet wird.

Ich denke, dass es keinen solchen logisch zwingenden Grund gibt, sondern dass die Redundanz in der Sprachgeschichte, in der **Etymologie** des Wortes liegt. Schauen wir uns also diese an (leider wird uns auch das nicht zu einer völlig zufriedenstellenden Antwort führen):

### Etymologie

Nach [Pfeifer *Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen*, Akademie-Verlag, Berlin, 1989](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Nabel), in Übereinstimmung mit Kluge<sup>24</sup> *Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache*, de Gruyter, Berlin, 2002, und Wahrig<sup>5</sup> *Herkunftswörterbuch*, Bertelsmann, 2009, kommt *Nabel*  von einer indoueuropäischen Wurzel **nā̌bʰ-* or **enebʰ* mit der Bedeutung "Nabel", und  "Nabe".

Pfeifer stellt klar, dass die Bedeutung "Zentrum" im Deutschen eine moderne Erscheinung ist:

> Die Bedeutung ‘Mittelpunkt’ tritt im Deutschen erst in jüngerer Sprache und nur in Genitivverbindungen (Nabel der Welt) auf.

Das ist überraschend, denn die konzeptuelle Mischung "Zentrum" und "Nabel" gibt es in vielen anderen Sprachen, etwa im altgriechichen "omphalos" (das die gleiche  Etymologie wie as deutsche "Nabel" hat), das den "Nabel der Welt" in Delphi und Jerusalem bezeichnet  (siehe [en:wikipedia: Omphalos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphalos)). I wäre sehr überrrascht, wenn omphalos *nicht* "Zentrum der Welt", sondern nur "Buckel" bedeutet hätte. Daher wundert es mich, dass "Zentrum" im Deuschen eine jüngere Bedeutun von "Nabel" ist.

Der [google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) und auch die Wortverlaufskurven von dwds.de zeigen, dass "Nabel" älter ist als "Bauchnabel", welcher letzterer zum ersten Mal im späten 18. Jahrhundert auftaucht:kann leider

### Nabel

[image: dwds.de: Wortverlaufskurve "Nabel", https://www.dwds.de/r/plot?q=Bauchnabel&view=1&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1600%3A2020]

[image: google ngram viewer "Nabel" between 1600 and 2000 in german publications, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nabel&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNabel%3B%2Cc0]

### Bauchnabel

[image: dwds.de: Wortverlaufskurve "Bauchnabel", https://www.dwds.de/r/plot?q=Nabel&view=1&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1600%3A2020]

[image: google ngram viewer "Bauchnabel" between 1700 and 2000 in german publications]

Ich kann aus diesen Befunden kein klares Bild ableiten. Am Ende lässt auch das alles sehr viel Raum für Spekulation. Dennoch kann ich zwei Hypothesen formulieren, die weitere Evidenz benötigen, um überprüft zu werden:

1. "Bauchnabel" erscheint in dem Zeitrum, in dem "Nabel" die zusätzliche übertragene Bedeutung "Zentrum"  erhält. Die Spezifikation wird als nötig empfunden, weil der Begriff "Nabel" nun in einer allgemeineren Bedeutung verstanden werden kann.
2. Am Anfang bezeichnete "Nabel" einen viel allgemeineren Begriff, etwa "Buckel". "Erhebung", oder ähnliches -- notabene, dass eine "Nabe" ja auch einen Buckel in der Mitte hat. Das Wort "Bauchnabel" könnte aus dieser Zeit stammen. Als dann später die Bedeutung "Nabel" auf "Bauchnabel" verengt wird, ist "Bauchnabel" bereits etabliert und wird weiterhin verwendet, auch wenn die Spezifikation logisch nicht mehr notwendig ist.

Aber ich gebe zu, dass das alles sehr spekulativ ist. Ich kann leider keine hinreichende Evidenz finden, um das aufzuklären. Aber vielleicht zeigen die Beispiele auf,  wie die Redundanz sprachgeschichtlich ***im Prinzip** entstehen kann*.

---

Your question has some different aspects and is based on some implicit assumptions. I will try to work out these assumptions in detail to give you a satisfying answer. I start with the more generic points and get more specific step by step:

### Redunancy

You seem to assume that language naturally tends to avoid redundancy - in the word "Bauchnabel" the information, that the "Nabel" belongs to the "Bauch" is redundant, when "Nabel" is logically equivalent to "Bauchnabel", i.e. when there are no other occurences of the word "Nabel". So, from a **logical** point of view the answer is: Languages are redundant. See [en:wikipedia: Redundancy (linguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(linguistics)) for examples and some explanations, why redundancy occurs in language at all.

It's not clear, whether your question shall be understood with that rather strict logical meaning (*Why is german language redundant in that point?*), but it's a possible interpretation. Of course that answer still leaves you with some questions. Given that languages are redundant, the uquestion remains, why we do  say "Bauchnabel" or "Augenbraue" but not *"Handfinger" or *"Kopfauge"? What is the difference? What makes "Bauchnabel" such a special case which differentiates it from *"Handfinger" which would be possible word as well, but does not exist?

The comment of Knut an the answer of Pollitzer point out that actually there are different usages of "Nabel", but I think these are very rare words, bound to specialist contexts. I would suppose that these special expressions - "Pflanzennabel", "Trommelfellnabel" and "Wassernabel" - are all younger than the word "Bauchnabel" and are not known to a wide variety of language-users who also use the word "Bauchnabel". Those people - who I guess make up the majority of competent german speakers - do use the word "Bauchnabel", but not because they need to confine the definition of "Nabel".

I think that the reason, why there is a second word for "Nabel", cannot be found by logical reasoning, but lies in the history, in the evolution, the **etymology** of the word. So let's have a look at it (alas, it won't give us a sufficient answer though):

### Etymology

According to [Pfeifer *Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen*, Akademie-Verlag, Berlin, 1989](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Nabel), according with Kluge<sup>24</sup> *Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache*, de Gruyter, Berlin, 2002, and Wahrig<sup>5</sup> *Herkunftswörterbuch*, Bertelsmann, 2009, *Nabel* comes from an indoueuropean word **nā̌bʰ-* or **enebʰ* with the meaning "Nabel", (english: *navel*, *umbilicus*) and "Nabe" (english: *hub*, *driving collar*).

Pfeifer points out, that the meaning "Zemtrum" (english *center*) of the word "Nabel" is a rather modern occurence in german:

> Die Bedeutung ‘Mittelpunkt’ tritt im Deutschen erst in jüngerer Sprache und nur in Genitivverbindungen (Nabel der Welt) auf.

That is suprising, since the conceptual blending of "navel" and "center" is present in many other languages, see for instance the ancient greek "omphalos" (with the same etymology as german "Nabel") which was seen as the "navel of the world" in both Delphi and Jerusalem  (see [en:wikipedia: Omphalos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphalos)). I would be very surprised if this would not have meant "center of the world" but only "hump", "hillock". So to me it is striking that "center" is a rather modern meaning of german "Nabel".

The [google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) as well as the word-trend-curves ("Wortverlaufskurve") of dwds.de show that "Nabel" is much older, while "Bauchnabel" occurs the first time in the late 18th century:

### Nabel

[image: dwds.de: Wortverlaufskurve "Nabel", https://www.dwds.de/r/plot?q=Bauchnabel&view=1&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1600%3A2020]

[image: google ngram viewer "Nabel" between 1600 and 2000 in german publications, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nabel&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNabel%3B%2Cc0]

### Bauchnabel

[image: dwds.de: Wortverlaufskurve "Bauchnabel", https://www.dwds.de/r/plot?q=Nabel&view=1&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1600%3A2020]

[image: google ngram viewer "Bauchnabel" between 1700 and 2000 in german publications]

I find it hard to make sense of this evidence. After all there is very much space for speculation left. After all I want to formulate two hypotheses which would need further evidence for clarification:

1. The occurence of "Bauchnabel" rises when the word "Nabel" gets the meaning "center" in german. (This concept is imported from other languages, like ancient greek for example)
2. In the very beginning "Nabel" just describes a more generic notion, like "Buckel" (english: *hump*, *hillock*) -- take notice, that "Nabe" (english "hub") also shows a kind of a "bump" in its center. The word "Bauchnabel" stems from this time. When "Nabel" gets the more specific meaning "navel", "Bauchnabel" is already established and continues living as a second variant, even if it is no longer necessary, since "Nabel" now clearly and always means "Bauchnabel".

But I have to admit that this all is no more than speculation. I cannot find suffficient evidence for neither of the two hypotheses. But maybe the examples show how the redundancy *could have been arising **in principle***.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese exzellente Antwort!

Comment: Danke für das Lob, aber beachte auch https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can actually use Nabel instead of Bauchnabel. However, Nabel can also have the meaning of centre such as "In der Antike war Rom der Nabel der Welt".

Eigentlich ist Bauchnabel der richtige Begriff, da er den Nabel am Bauch bezeichnet. Nabel für sich alleine ist ein allgemeiner Begriff, der, wie schon erläutert, ein Zentrum bezeichnet. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, nehme aber an, dass es denselben Ursprung wie Nabe hat, also das Zentrum eines Rades. Wenn jemand das Wort Nabel für den Bauchnabel verwendet, ist das eine Verkürzung, die sich wohl aus Bequemlichkeit im Lauf der Zeit entwickelt hat.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer my question **why** it is also called Bauchnabel instead of just Nabel.

Comment: Weil Deutsch eine präzise Sprache ist. Eigentlich ist Bauchnabel der richtige Begriff, da er den Nabel am Bauch bezeichnet. Nabel für sich alleine ist ein allgemeiner Begriff, der, wie schon erläutert, ein Zentrum bezeichnet. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, nehme aber an, dass es denselben Ursprung wie Nabe hat, also das Zentrum eines Rades. Wenn jemand das Wort Nabel für den Bauchnabel verwendet, ist das eine Verkürzung, die sich wohl aus Bequemlichkeit im Lauf der Zeit entwickelt hat.

Comment: Im Wiktionary heißt es: *übertragen*: der Mittelpunkt von Etwas. Woher wissen wir, dass Nabel (*Mittelpukt von Etwas*) nicht von Bauchnabel kommt?

Comment: Das ist eine recht spekulative Antwort. Schau mal: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/umgang-mit-spekulativen-antworten

Answer (score 4):

In der Botanik gibt es den **[Pflanzennabel](http://universal_lexikon.deacademic.com/110817/Pflanzennabel)**, auch ([das](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hilum)) [**Hilum**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilum) genannt. Das ist die Stelle, an der der Same angewachsen war. Neben dem Bauchnabel gibt es also auch andere Nabel – ein möglicher Grund, warum man statt *»Bauchnabel«* nicht einfach nur *»Nabel«* sagt.

Wie *@Karl Krieger* und *@Hubert Schölnast* richtig bemerken, werden *»Bauchnabel«* und das abkürzende *»Nabel«* gleichermaßen verwendet. Anders bei

> Nabelschnur

das mit führendem *»Bauch«* in Jahrzehnten nie in mein Gehör gedrungen ist, auch nicht im aktuellen [Duden](http://www.duden.de/) steht. Das mag daran liegen, dass Nabelschnüre grundsätzlich an einem Bauch befestigt sind.

Answer (score 3):

Beide Begriffe sind erlaubt und gängig. Das ist so ähnlich wie mit den Brauen oder Lidern. Die hat man auch nirgendwo als über bzw. an den Augen, trotzdem sagt man sehr oft

> Augenbrauen
>   Augenlid

Weder die langen noch die kurzen Begriffe sind falsch oder stilistisch schlecht. Es existieren eben jeweils zwei Formen als Synonyme. Einige Menschen bevorzugen die lange Form, andere die kurze. Mehr steckt da nicht dahinter.

Answer (score 1):

@jonathan.scholbach
 Has a very long and good analysis of the etymology.

My take is to look at the word and how it is actually used.

Others pointed out that **"Rad-Nabe"** and **"Bauch-Nabel"** may be related.
How? Both are connections. One is to the Mother, the other is to the Axle.

Another related word is **"abgenabelt"**. It means to be no longer connected to something.

So if **"abgenabelt"** means disconnected, **"genabelt"** must mean connected.

> Thus --> **Nabel = Connection**